# Not Getting Post Request Response - swift

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, swift

I Have java web-services. The web-services are with HTTPS. I am handling authentication challenge using following code, however server is not responding with any response when I call POST method

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge) {


    if challengeUsername.isEqualToString("") || challengePassword.isEqualToString("") {

    }
    else
    {
        if challenge.previousFailureCount == 0{

            println("Received Authentication challenge")

            var nCredentials : NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential(user: challengeUsername, password: challengePassword, persistence: .ForSession)
            var trustRef:SecTrustRef  = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!//challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust
            var count:CFIndex = SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trustRef)
            if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
            {
           // challenge.sender.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
                    challenge.sender.useCredential(nCredentials, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
            //challenge.sender.performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge!(challenge)
            }
            else
            {
                challenge.sender.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
            }
            println("Responded to authentication challenge")

        }
        else
        {
            println("Previous authentication failed")
        }
    }

}
```

if I call GET web-service it get correct response and data too. not sure why this is happening, any kind of help is appreciated. Also I would like to know how can I use self signed certificate with web-service request?

Comment: Did you set the HTTP method of your request to "POST"?

Comment: Hi Sudeep, 
no that is not the case. I am using HTTPS for POST as well.